# how to get record count of deleted rows using deleteInBatch method of jpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${trackingdetailspurge.cron.expression}")
void oldRecordPurgeDailyCron() {
    List<TrackingEvent> listTrackingEvent = trackingEventDao.findByEventDate(450, "AUDIT_EVENT");
    logger.info("--Before Tracking_event purge execution | no of records :"+listTrackingEvent.size());
    trackingEventDao.deleteInBatch(listTrackingEvent);
    logger.info("Tracking event purge completed | no of records :"+listTrackingEvent.size()+" | "+listTrackingEvent.get(0).getId());
    List<Tracking> listTracking = trackingDao.findByUpdateDate(450);}
}
```

---

This is what I am doing so far.

It is giving stackoverflow error. it is 1 million records I am trying delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, if you are trying to delete so many records, then i would suggest splitting the list in even groups and removing those groups iteratively, each in its own separate transaction.

Thanks to that you can calculate the maximum entities in a batch do not cause the StackOverflow and are processed with greatest speed. Also you would not block other transactions for too long which might be an important point to consider.

**1)** Create a service method which would always be run in a new, isolated transaction:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void deleteEventsInBatch(List<TrackingEvent events){
    trackingEventDao.deleteInBatch(events);
}
```

**2)** Change your scheduled method to split the original list and invoke the aforementioned service method in a loop.

Now you can keep the counter and update it after each successfull service call. If one of the fails, then the counter value will hold the deleted rows so far.

Comment: Ok thanx a lot. I also want to ask how to get deleted record count in this.?

Comment: I included the idea on how to do that also

Comment: it is working for around 2000 record without splitting..but for more records it is giving 'socket closed' exception.. so is splitting the only way?

Comment: That the way i have been personally dealing with batches like that. Possibly there are some other ways but this is the idea that i bring to the table. The call is yours whether to use it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the records to be deleted need to be examined in detail before being deleted, it is not necessary to fetch records in memory in order to delete them and finding the number of deleted records. The following should work:

```
interface TrackingEventRepository extends CrudRepository<TrackingEvent, Long> {
  @Modifying
  @Query("delete from TrackingEvent e where e.date = ?1")
  @Transactional
  int deleteByEventDate(int date);
}
```

---

The above repository method can be invoked as `trackingEventRepository.deleteByEventDate(450)` and will directly delete the required records from the database without loading them into memory. The return value of the method will indicate the number of records affected by the query, which in this case will be the number of deleted records.

A [sample project](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/43821990) is available on Github to demonstrate this in action.